# How to mark an event as "Looked At" in Logstash

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, get, logstash, put

So I am querying Logstash with this query, which returns all the things off of the top of the stack:

```
{
"query": {
"match_all": { }
},
"size": 7,
"_source": {
"includes": [ "transport", "dest", "packet_source", "id_orig_p", "id_orig_p", "id_orig_h", "conn_state", "id_resp_h", "id_resp_p", "service", "proto" ]
} ,
"sort": [
  {
    "@timestamp": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
] 
}
```

However, as I query the data then I get duplicates if there is no new data coming in. Is there a way to mark each unique event id as "LookedAt" with an integer field or something?

I need to do this to reduce the garbage collection of my queries in C#, but storing all the ID's and doing string comparisons is pretty heavy, and seems unnecessary when I have Logstash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is to use a timestamp and include it in your query. For instance, from the results of the first query you can take the timestamp of the latest event (i.e. the first one in the results), and then when you make the second query you ask for events whose timestamp is higher than that timestamp.

So, you make the first query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 7,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "transport",
      ...
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then say that in the results, the timestamp of the latest event is `2017-02-28T10:02:23.000Z`.

The next query would then be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gt": "2017-02-28T10:02:23.000Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 7,
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "transport",
      ...
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And so on, you'd be guaranteed to never have a duplicate event.

Comment: I get the following error when doing that:

`{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "[range] query does not support [runtime_timestamp]",
        "line" : 5,
        "col" : 9
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[range] query does not support [runtime_timestamp]",
    "line" : 5,
    "col" : 9
  },
  "status" : 400
}`

Comment: What is the type of your `runtime_timestamp` field?